# Systemctl service: Unit not found when run as non-root

Tags: linux, systemd

I have the following custom systemctl service definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=DIALOG communication control server
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=daq
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/online/subsystems/daq/RCCARS/amber-rccars-lib/lib/release/"
Environment="PATH=/usr/sue/sbin:/usr/sue/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin"
Environment="DIALOG_CONTROL_SERVER_PORT=55550"

ExecStart=/online/subsystems/daq/RCCARS/amber-rccars-daq/DIALOGCommunicationControlServer/bin/release/_rccars_DIALOGCommunicationControlServer


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `daq` user should be able to restart this service without a root password, so I have added this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

`%daq ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart DIALOGServer.service`

The restart works as root, but as the `daq` user, I get the following:

`sudo -l`:

```
Matching Defaults entries for daq on pcamma00:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY
    HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
    env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC
    LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User daq may run the following commands on pcamma00:
    (daq) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (daq) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart DIALOGServer.service
```

If I type:

`sudo /bin/systemctl restart DIALOGServer.service`

I get:

`Failed to restart DIALOGServer.service: Unit not found`

Any idea why the unit is not found when I am not root?

Comment: Is the unit found by `systemctl status -n 0 DIALOGServer.service` (as root, as non-root via sudo, and as non-root directly)?

Comment: Yes to all three, (the second one, I had to add a sudoers line for).